# How to synchronize react app automatically when someone do changes in it on another account?

Tags: reactjs, automation, react-query

I am Developing the Hospital Management System and it is almost completed. I want to fully synchronize the Queue Management so that when the current token changes on a screen should show the updates immediately on another. How to do it? I used react and react query for API.

I used query invalidation but it showed result only in the same account and app not in others

Comment: You want it like a chat apps? for example, someone reserve appointment, the other see it real time?

Comment: If you need data reflected across multiple users in real time, there's essentially 2 approaches: sockets or polling

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The app will be shown on screen on different positions like doctors doors, main lobby etc and also the admin computer. If the current token changes in one place, admin should see it automatically. similarly for others.

Comment: @Jayce444 what is polling?

Comment: @MuhammadAbbasKhan polling is just periodically calling the API from the front end, say every 5 seconds, so that it gets up to date data constantly